# Xcode7: Invalid code signing entitlements

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode7

I am trying to archive my app to submit to the app store.  I have tried every single advice on this topic, but I still can't seem to get rid of the following error:

**Archive submission failed due to the issues listed below.**

**ERROR ITMS-90046: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. Your application bundle's signature contains code signing entitlements that are not supported on iOS. Specifically, value '*' for key 'com.apple.developer.associated-domains' in 'Payload/FeedTheTribe7.app/FeedTheTribe7' is not supported."**

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Dev Center > App Id > remove associated domains check

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the reason given below is also responsible for this error

**If you install provisioning profile before installing distribution certificate cause this error**

To solve this error, remove provisioning profile and reinstall it, will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If this problem still occuring, I removed all provisionning profiles listed as invalid and I reuploaded it and it worked fine.

See this conversation for different solutions but only the solution listed above worked for me.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/12758

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the version number in iTunes Connect is same as the app's version number given in Xcode.